# Spinnaker gate error: LDAP error: Could not get a resource from the pool

Tags: spinnaker

any suggestion, does this LDAP config for GATE looks ok. I am having some issue with LDAP config for Gate:

```
ldap:
  enabled: true
  url: ldap://10.19.11.12:389/dc=xxxx,dc=corp
  userDnPattern: uid={0},ou=abc,ou=service accounts
  managerDn: uid=testuser
  managerPassword: abc123
```

getting below errors in Gate error logs:

````
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:16) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]```
````

Answer (score 0):

jedis is the redis library. Its not able to connect to your redis server.

Your gate config looks correct.